# Is it a good practice to set interrupt affinity and io handling thread affinity to the same core?

Tags: performance, networking, linux-kernel, interrupt

I am trying to understand irq affinity and its impact to system performance.

I went through [why-interrupt-affinity-with-multiple-cores-is-not-such-a-good-thing](http://www.alexonlinux.com/why-interrupt-affinity-with-multiple-cores-is-not-such-a-good-thing), and learnt that NIC irq affinity should be set to a different core other then the core that handling the network data, since the handling will not be interrupted by incoming irq.

I doubt this, since if we use a different core to handling the data from the irq core, we will get more cache miss when trying to retrieve the network data from kernel. So I am actually believe that by setting the irq affinity as the same core of the thread handling the incoming data will improve performance due to less cache miss.

I am trying to come up with some verification code, but before I will present any results, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

IRQ affinity is a double edged sword. In my experience it can improve performance but only in a very specific configuration with a pre-defined workload. As far as your question is concerned, (consider only RX path) typically when a NIC card interrupts one of the core, in majority of the cases the interrupt handler will *not* do much, except for triggering a mechanism (bottom-half, tasklet, kernel thread or networking stack thread) to process incoming packet in some other context. If the same packet processing core is handling the interrupts (ISR handler does not do much), it is bound to loose some cache benefit due to context switches and may increase cache misses. How much is the impact, depends on variety of other factors.

In NIC drivers typically, affinity of core is aligned to each RX queue [separating each RX queue processing across different cores], which provides more performance benefit.

Comment: The default affinity is distributed IRQ to all cores in RR way? And according to what you described, by excluding the handling core from IRQ affinity is a promising way to gain performance benefit.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but practically it may not matter much. Also there are other ways to gain better performance e.g. coalesced interrupts or polling

Answer (score 1):

Controlling interrupt affinity can have quite few useful applications. Few that sprint to mind.

- isolating cores - preventing I/O load spreading onto mission critical CPU cores, or cores that exclusive for RT priority (scheduled softirqs could starve on those)
- increase system performance - throughput and latency - by keeping interrupts on relevant NUMA for multi-CPU systems
- CPU efficiency - e.g. dedicating CPU, NIC channel with its interrupt to single application will squeeze more from that CPU, about 30% more with heavy traffic usecases.
  This might require flow steering to make incoming traffic target the channel.
  Note: without affinity app might seem to deliver more throughput but would spill load onto many cores). The gains is thanks to cache locality, and context switch prevention.
- latency - setting up application as above will halve the latency (from 8us to 4us on modern system)